# Lightning record edit form is not going to detail page after saving record

Tags: lightning-aura-components

After saving contact details, record is saved but it's not redirecting to contact detail page.

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable" >
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
<div class="slds-p-bottom_large slds-p-left_large" style="width:500px">
    <lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="Contact">
        <lightning:messages />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="FirstName" />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="LastName" />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Birthdate" />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Phone" />
        <lightning:button aura:id="submit" type="submit" label="Save record" class="slds-m-top_medium" />
        </lightning:recordEditForm>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That’s because you have to code the redirection using the onsuccess event. The default behaviour is , does nothing on save,  you will have to retrieve the Id of the record from the response object and use it to redirect to the appropriate record detail page/view. The component documentation has several code snippets that will help you achieve the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

After successfully editing/saving record you can handle on success event:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable" >
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
<div class="slds-p-bottom_large slds-p-left_large" style="width:500px">
    <lightning:recordEditForm 
        objectApiName="Contact"
        onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}">
        <lightning:messages />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="FirstName" />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="LastName" />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Birthdate" />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Phone" />
        <lightning:button aura:id="submit" type="submit" label="Save record" class="slds-m-top_medium" />
        </lightning:recordEditForm>
        <lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>
</div>
```

In Controller:

```
({
    handleSuccess : function(component, event, helper) {
    var payload = event.getParams().response;
    var navService = component.find("navService");

    var pageReference = {
        type: 'standard__recordPage',
        attributes: {
            "recordId": payload.id,
            "objectApiName": "Contact",
            "actionName": "view"
        }
    }
    event.preventDefault();
    navService.navigate(pageReference);  
    }    
})
```

Comment: What does the event.preventDefault() do in this code?